# Why does Array.Copy support Long Arguments

Tags: c#, arrays

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btfeahds(VS.80).aspx):

> Parameters sourceArray
>
> The Array that contains the data to
>   copy. destinationArray
>
> The Array that receives the data.
>   length
>
> A 64-bit integer that represents the
>   number of elements to copy. The
>   integer must be between zero and
>   Int32.MaxValue, inclusive

Given that the permitted range of values is `0` to `Int32.MaxValue`, what is the motivation for adding this signature?  It did not exist in .Net 1.0 and was only added in .Net 1.1.  My only guess is to prepare for 64-bit Framework implementations.

Comment: or a legacy hangup - never forget they are mere mortals at MS too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Curiously an array also has overloads for [GetItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getvalue.aspx) that take either an Int32 and an Int64. But in practice you cannot have a single object larger than 2 gigabytes in the current implementation of the .NET framework so you can't actually create an array that allows such large indexes.

I guess if this restriction were lifted later then it would mean that they don't need to change the interface.

Comment: That makes me wonder if one could define an array with a lower bound > int.MaxValue...

Comment: @dtb: Not using `CreateInstance` because the length parameter is an int.  If you try to do something like `Array my1DIntArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(Int64), new int[] { 3 }, new int[] { Int32.MaxValue - 1 });` , you get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` with the message, `Array my1DIntArray = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(Int64), new int[] { 3 }, new int[] { Int32.MaxValue - 1 });`